# React Native and sqlite migrations

Tags: sqlite, react-native

It's difficult to find a lot of examples of people using sqlite with their react native apps.

I'm going to be using this library : https://github.com/craftzdog/react-native-sqlite-2

Is there a good option out there for managing the client db schema post-launch? On our server apps we have a migration lib that does the work of deciding which "migrations" should be run. Is there something similar for RN or is it a "do it yourself" situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's a "do it yourself" situation in React Native. I've made a migration table which tracks which migrations have already been run along with a timestamp. All migrations not in the table get run upon launch.

Comment: i have some issues with the sqlite in react native, can you help me please ?

Comment: @shira sure, although you could make a new post for your question